nestjs connecting to Redis usng CacheModule but importing fails
I have imported Redis external info from .env in "APPMODULE" and CacheModule in "RedisModule" as below. I've also injected CacheManager in "AuthService.ts". But an error saying " Nest can't resolve dependencies of the CACHE_MANAGER (?). Please make sure that the argument "CACHE_MODULE_OPTIONS" at index [0] is available in the CacheModule context.". I have tried many things but none working. What should I do?
"RedisModule"
import { ConfigModule, ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import * as redisStore from 'cache-manager-redis-store';
import { CacheModule } from '@nestjs/cache-manager';

@Module({
  imports: [
    CacheModule.registerAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      inject: [ConfigService],
      useFactory: async (cfg: ConfigService) => ({
        store: redisStore,
        host: cfg.get('REDIS_HOST'),
        user: cfg.get('REDIS_USER'),
        password: cfg.get('REDIS_PASSWORD'),
        port: cfg.get('REDIS_PORT'),
        ttl: cfg.get('REDIS_TTL'),
      }),

      isGlobal: true,
    }),
  ],
})
export class RedisModule {}


"AuthService.ts"
import { CACHE_MANAGER } from '@nestjs/cache-manager';
import { Cache } from 'cache-manager';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  constructor(
    private readonly userService: UserService,
    private readonly configService: ConfigService,
    private readonly jwtService: JwtService,
    private readonly emailService: EmailService,
    @Inject(CACHE_MANAGER) private cacheManager: Cache,
  ) {}


It looks like that the CacheModule is still not initialized. I don't have any experience with this Cache module. You can try to move the CacheModule to the app module and test again.
